# A word or phrase roughly meaning "you are the cause of the problem you try to cure"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've heard it used in a religious contexts along the lines of

> They invent the problem which they claim to solve.

I know it's also common in marketing, where if I try to sell you a pen, I ask you to sign your name, then offer to sell you the pen.

It's like creating the problem, so that you can then offer your solution.

Comment: In this clip they use *vertical integration* to describe a similar situation, one in which a company manufactures diarrhea-inducing junk food only to then sell the afflicted a diarrhea medicine: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ7oht6TD9c. But their use of this term deviates somewhat from its normal meaning.

Comment: A reference to [Ya Got Trouble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LI_Oe-jtgdI) would work in some places. From The Music Man.

Comment: You're not the problem-solver; you're the instigator.

Answer (score 2):

One expression that may be relevant is "**setting fire to [something] just so you can put it out**." A concrete example of this expression appears in "[Setting Fire Okeh; Putting It Out ...?](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=336&dat=19450823&id=kFszAAAAIBAJ&sjid=kncDAAAAIBAJ&pg=4377,4976325&hl=en)" in the *[Salt Lake City, Utah] Deseret News* (August 24, 1945):

> LOS ANGELES —(AP)—The federal grand jury returned an indictment today charging that Ossie Gordon Wynns, 24, a Tulare, Calif., forestry service fire guard, deliberately set a disastrous forest fire just to show that he could put it out.
>
> Instead, the fire got out of hand and burned over 1300 acres of Sequoia National Park forest land, the indictment charged.

Supposedly, in the bad old days of the mid-20th century, traveling vacuum-cleaner salesman used a similar tactic, unexpectedly throwing a handful of dirt on a homeowner's carpet so that they could then demonstrate how effectively the machine they were selling could clean up the mess. That might be described as "**throwing dirt on the carpet so you can vacuum it up**."

Answer (score 1):

John Kenneth Galbraith is reported to have invented the term "[**revised-sequence markets**](http://lynnemctaggart.com/blog/263-inventing-the-problem)" to describe this phenomenon in the context of economics.  As stated in the [*linked article*](http://lynnemctaggart.com/blog/263-inventing-the-problem)

> ...to put it more simply, they invent the problem to sell the
>   solution.

The usage here, though, may be more narrowly applicable to business than to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [problem reaction solution](http://ethics.wikia.com/wiki/Problem_Reaction_Solution) and [hegelian principle](http://www.theforbiddenknowledge.com/hardtruth/hegelian_principle.htm).

Creating a problem, thus creating a reaction and then providing the solution constitute the essence of those two terms.

You can say **they follow the hegelian principle or the problem reaction solution principle.**

Comment: Neither of these is close. PRS (which seems born of the fever dreams of right-wing conspiracy theorists) means creating a crisis and advocating a solution to advance a pre-determined agenda by a means that would be unpopular in the absence of the crisis.  The Hegelian principle is that a *thesis* (a motivating idea) begets its *antithesis* (the opposite of the thesis in reaction) and their collision produces a new thesis (the *synthesis*), and the cycle can begin anew.